# Maven Update Project: CreateProcess error=2: Cannot find \bin\java

Tags: java, maven

I  can't update my maven-project anymore beacause it seems like it can't find the java executable in the path specified in the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute(Commandline.java:655)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Translation of the error:
The system can not find the specified file

What could be the cause here? The specified path with java does clearly exist on my system as you can see in the provided screenshot.

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't. The path you show is `C:\Program Files (x86)\...`. If you want to have the JDK in the path `C:\Program Files\...`, you have to install the 64 bit version.

Comment: I installed the 64-Bit of the JDK jsut a few mintues ago. I now set the path in Eclipse to the actual destination where the 64 bit is installed, now i am getting the error that 'Main class jdk64 could not be found'